# How to import custom functions on my experiment script for Azure ML?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service

I can successfully submit an experiment to processing on a remote compute target on Azure ML.

In my notebook, for submitting the experiment, I have:

```
# estimator
estimator = Estimator(
    source_directory='scripts',
    entry_script='exp01.py',
    compute_target='pc2',
    conda_packages=['scikit-learn'],
    inputs=[data.as_named_input('my_dataset')],
    )

# Submit
exp = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='my_exp')

# Run the experiment based on the estimator
run = exp.submit(config=estimator)
RunDetails(run).show()
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

However, in order to keep things clean, I want to define my general use functions on an auxiliary script, so the first will import it.

On my script experiment file exp01.py, I wanted:

```
import custom_functions as custom

# azure experiment start
run = Run.get_context()

# the data from azure datasets/datastorage
df = run.input_datasets['my_dataset'].to_pandas_dataframe()

# prepare data
df_transformed = custom.prepare_data(df)

# split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = custom.split_data(df_transformed)

# run my models.....
model_name = 'RF'
model = custom.model_x(model_name, a_lot_of_args)

# log the results
run.log(model_name, results)

# azure finish
run.complete()
```

The thing is: Azure wont let me import the custom_functions.py.

How are you doing it?

Answer (score 3):

`TL;DR` any files you put inside the `source_directory` in your case, `scripts` will be available to the Estimator.

To make this happen, simply create a file called `custom_functions.py` in the `scripts` folder that contains your `prepare_data()`, `split_data()`, `model_x()` functions.

I also recommend that you include only exactly what you need in the `source_directory` folder and make distinct folders for each Estimator because:

- the entire folder's contents will be uploaded when you use a remote compute_target, and
- when you started using ML Pipeilnes (which are awesome), `PythonScriptStep`s `allow_reuse` parameter will look to see if any files in the `source_directory` have changed when determining if the step needs to run again or not.

Lastly, when you want to share general utility functions across `PythonScriptStep`s or Estimators without having to copy and paste code, that's when you might want to consider creating a custom python package.

Comment: It worked! Placing custom_functions.py in the scripts folder and importing it directly (as being on the same level) worked. Thanks!